# A Complexity Problem of Cliques

Tags: computational-complexity

I've been trying to figure out the Karp Reduction
$$CLIQUE(G,k)  \preceq IND(G,k),$$
Where $CLIQUE(G,k)$ is the decision problem "Is there a clique of size at least $k$ in the graph $G$" and $IND(G,k)$ is the decision problem ``Is there an independent set of size at least $k$ in the graph $G$." I have a  feeling that this reduction has something to do with the edges available in the Graph $G$, but I am also wondering if it would be better to find another decision problem that $CLIQUE(G,k)$ reduces to in the hopes that it will easily reduce to $IND(G,k).$ Any suggestions? Should I consider the vertices in a potential clique in $G$?